# Access variable from .h file in class methods of .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, atomic, class-method

I need to create a variable with atomic property for thread safety and access it in  class variable.
If I can't what are my other options

```
   @property(atomic, weak) NSArray *myArray;
   +(void)Fuction  {
     self.myarray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
   }
```

Comment: Add language tag, please.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Is there supposed to be only one `myArray` for the entire class or one for each instance?

Comment: No,I have this array to append the objects downloaded from server. But the array is being read by other threads before completion of write.So I get incomplete array.  I want to make it thread safe by making it atomic using @ property. But @ property can only be used for global variables. and global variables can't be used in class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could get access to the property in a class method, I don't think `atomic` would solve the problem.  It sounds as if you need synchronization while you're doing the appends.  (Or append to a local variable and then assign it to `myArray`.)

There's a good article on doing this with queues at https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html.  Look at the part called "Custom Concurrent Queues and Barriers".

He shows how to protect a dictionary, but an array isn't significantly different for this purpose.

Comment: I used @synchronized to fix the issue but the  .As the array is being used  in different places @ synchronized (){ } block is more than 25 lines   which i think is big and may is making the process bit slower. Wondering if theres is any better solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The nice thing about his queue solution is that readers don't block other readers (which is a potential problem with @synchronized).